# count items from 1 column and split them into two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two tables, data and agentdata.

`data (agentid, SimCardNumber, ProductName, Agentemail)`

agentdata `(id, agentid, ProductName)`

currently i deal only two products and i want to view this list as group by agentemail

```
agentemail    |  Product1  |  Total1   |  Product2  |  Total2
-----------------------------------------------------------
abc@gmail.com |  ball      |   5       |  bat       |  0
```

i tried this query but i have problem to show two products and their count side by side.

```
SELECT a.agentid,  d.Agentemail, a.ProductName, COUNT(a.ProductName) AS Total  
FROM  data AS d, agentdata AS a 
WHERE d.agentid=a.agentid
GROUP BY a.ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL isn't built to handle side-by-side things like that. It works on rows, you want it to display columns.

Your original query should `GROUP BY agentid, ProductName` to separate out the agents from the product totals.

If you know that you only have two product and no more, you can write a query to display just those two products side-by-side. If you add a third product, it will not include it.

```
SELECT a.agentid,  d.Agentemail, 
    'ball' AS Product1, 
    SUM(IF(a.ProductName = 'ball', 1, 0)) AS Total1,  
    'bat' AS Product2, 
    SUM(IF(a.ProductName = 'bat', 1, 0)) AS Total2,  
FROM  data AS d, agentdata AS a 
WHERE d.agentid=a.agentid
GROUP BY agentid
```

This sort of query is OK for doing quick checks on data, but your front-end should use a more solid query and build the table there.

Answer (score 0):

```
data (agentid, SimCardNumber, ProductName, Agentemail)

agentdata (id, agentid, ProductName)
```

You should REALLY think about your table layout. if `agentid == agentid` and `ProductName == ProductName`, this layout is against everything a normalized database would store - and therefore no queries that actually make sence are possible...

- do you want a `1:1` relation? (One Agent, one Product): Then you dont need the agentdata-table at all.
- do you want a `1:n` relation? (One Agent, multipe Products): Then you don't need the `ProductName` in the data-table.
- do you want a `n:1` relation? (Multiple Agents, One Product): Then you don't need the `agentid` in the agentdata-table.
- do you want a `n:n` relation? (Multiple Agents, Multiple Products): Then you need to remove `ProductName` from the data-table, remove `agentid` from the agentdata-table and create a Mapping Table with `ProductName` and `agentid` on which you finally could join your data- and agentdata-table.

With this layout - and without knowing *what* data is stored where, it's impossible to give an answer that *really* helps you with your problem.